# Achieve the same as hitting tab in word

Tags: latex

I want to display

```
AFM   Atomic force microscope
ii    Information Technology
```

[image]

but i am getting as above there is a shift in position of word 'Atomic' i want it to coe directly under 'Aacef'.
How to acieve tht

Comment: How do you get your current ouput?  Is this meant to be a list or more of an array? The solution depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to not manually format the list, but let latex do the formatting for you. In theory you could use a table without lines, but instead of reinventing the wheel, use one of the existing packages for abbreviations https://ctan.org/topic/acronym

Here an example using the `accro` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{array}

\DeclareAcronym{afm}{
  short=AFM,
  long=Atomic force microscope
}

\DeclareAcronym{ii}{
  short=ii,
  long=Information Technology
}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms[display=all,template=tabular]

\end{document}
```

[image]